# Having a 0 in front of a string of numbers

Tags: vb.net, string, numbers

So what I have here is I've ran a select statement and I'm simply displaying the results.  This pulls a serial number that is 11 digits.  Some of the number's start with 0.  The number is displayed and incremented by 1.  So in this example the number being pulled here is "01400010001".  However I cannot figure out how to display this.  No matter what I've tried it takes off the "0" from the beginning.  No matter what I end up doing to add that "0" at the start, it needs to be replaceable by any other number for when its not a "0".

```
    If rsMPCS.HasRows Then
        Dim mti_serial As Double = (CStr(rsMPCS("mti_part_no")))

        Label43.Text = mti_serial.ToString("00000000000") + 1
```

Comment: This code could never work if you set the Option Strict On as you should. Do you really have a part number in a double format?

Comment: Be carefull here, you are mixing strings and numbers in an improper way. You should convert rsMPCS to double and make sure to add 1 before converting back to string.

Comment: I only recently converted to double when I was troubleshooting.  previously it was a String.

Comment: If I just do this then it works.

                Dim mti_serial As String = (CStr(rsMPCS("mti_part_no")))

                Label43.Text = mti_serial

but once I add +1 the 0 goes away from the beginning of the number.

Comment: But in your database table is still a string. However it doesn't contain any alphabetic chars but only digits, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your field (on the database table) is of type string with only digits then you could increment it in this way

```
If rsMPCS.HasRows Then
    Dim mti_serial As Long = Convert.ToInt64(rsMPCS("mti_part_no"))
    mti_serial = mti_serial + 1
    Label43.Text = mti_serial.ToString("D11") 
End If
```

This works using the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) provided by the NET Framework

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thank you Steve.